# Getting tabular statistics from table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, statistics

Are there QGIS tools that will allow users to get tabular statistics from their table?  I kind of expected I would be able to just open the table, select the field I was interested in, right-click on the field header and get something similar to this (screenshot taken from ArcGIS):

[image: frequency report]

More specifically, I am looking for a QGIS alternative to the ArcGIS [Frequency](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001w000000) and [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tools, that offer a [host of other stats](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20605/frequency-summarize-tool) you can retrieve about the tabular data.

---

Just after asking, I found [this QGIS Tutorial](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/spatial_statistics.html) (see section 4.2 ) that describes how to find this functionality... Vector > Analysis Tools > Basic statistics.  I also found Vector > Analysis Tools > List Unique Values right next to it.  This gets me the list of unique values, but I would also like to see an additional column of frequency (count) of each unique item.  Is this similar tool available "out-of-the-box"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**Statist**](http://gis-lab.info/qa/statist-eng.html) plugin is going to be your friend here:

[image]

IMHO - it beats ESRI approach hands down with both functionality and aesthetics.

---

For looking at groupings of your data I'd also recommend [**Group Stats**](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) plugin:

[image]

Although (afaik) it doesn't work with single variables, it comes really handy for getting quick summaries of most important parameters of distribution of certain variable across groups of other variable. And yet again - ESRI is far beyond here.

---

I've also seen [**Spqr**](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Software/Spqr/) out there, but haven't had chance to give it a proper spin. It works with R and looks really promising, but seems to be still in early days, and as author suggests it is:

> For experts and crazy people only. Bits of this aren't implemented and
>   other bits don't work and most of it will break if you push it.

Comment: Group Stats is a great little utility. Its a shame that the field sorting for numeric values like count, sum, etc uses alphanumeric sorting (ie- 1,10,100,2,21,3,350) instead of numeric sorting.  But the fact that you can at least copy/paste the results into a spreadsheet and re-sort that way makes it pretty useful.

Comment: I have submitted a [bug report](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6827) for Group Stats sorting.

Comment: @RyanDalton I agree - from my perspective it would be much more desirable to have numeric sorting in 90% of the cases. Let's hope your report will get noticed :]

Comment: It looks like [the bug report for sorting numerically](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6827) will be fixed in an upcoming release (updated 1/16/2013).  That's great sounding news!

Comment: This plugin no more in QGIS.

Answer (score 4):

Years later, I had the same question with QGIS 2.18.16, and I came across this thread.

The QGIS alternative to the Arc Frequency tool is:

Toolbox > QGIS Geoalgorithms > Vector table tools > Frequency Analysis

Answer (score 2):

there is also the tool **statistic by categories** beside the tool basic statistics. It is similar to the one in ArcGIS where you can get statistics for fields one based on another