# Programmatically finding polygons which are >90% overlapped by another vector polygon layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

[image: Example layers]

I'm trying to figure out how to use python to extract the polygons in one vector that are overlapped by >90% by another vector.  I would then like to have a vector/map that will only show those polygons.  The example picture shows my layers.  I want all the grey polygons that are > 90% red.

I need to do this all via python (or similarly automated methods). I have ~1000 maps to process the same way.

Comment: You want to do an overlay 'union' (see https://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/geo-processing-in-qgis/ for some basics) then for each original polygon calculate the 'in' statistics and 'out' statistics http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/getting-tabular-statistics-from-table-using-qgis to determine the overlay percent... hint: you need to have an area measurement http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks for the tips. That's the same approach I was just attempting.  I can do the union through the python console easy enough.  Already added in the area attribute values.  It's the next step I'm unsure of.  How do I use python to calculate the  'in' and 'out' statistics so that I can identify/select/clip etc. the >90% polygons?

Comment: I think it's possible without python. Do you need absolutly python or a solution with virtual layers is good for you ?

Comment: The 'in' areas will have attributes from both polygons, the 'out' areas only have attributes from one set of polygons. Get both sets of area statistics and join back to the original polygons, add a field for 'in', 'out' and coverage, calculate the values for 'in' and 'out' from the sum of areas then divide 'in' by the original area (or 'in' + 'out') to calculate percent.

Comment: How would I sum areas by attribute in python?  Can't seem to come up with an example via GoogleFu.

Comment: Pierma - I just need an automated method to find the polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code works in my Python Console of QGIS. It produces a memory layer with polygons which are > 90% overlapped by red areas.

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

#for polygon_intersects
feats_lyr1 = [ feat for feat in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

#for xwRcl
feats_lyr2 = [ feat for feat in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

selected_feats = []

for i, feat1 in enumerate(feats_lyr1):
    area1 = 0
    area2 = 0
    for j, feat2 in enumerate(feats_lyr2):
        if feat1.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
            area = feat1.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry()).area()
            print i, j, area, feat2.attribute('class')
            if feat2.attribute('class') == 1:
                area1 += area
            else:
                area2 += area
    crit = area1/(area1 + area2)
    print crit
    if crit > 0.9:
        selected_feats.append(feat1)

epsg = layers[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           "mem_layer",
                           "memory")

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(selected_feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])

prov.addFeatures(selected_feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

I tried out the code with these two vector layers:

[image]

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, for corroborating results, there were printed the indexes i, j of involved features, intersection areas, attribute of field in **polygons_intersects** (1 for red areas and 2 for gray areas) and the overlapping criterion.

```
0 0 9454207.56892 1
0 1 17429206.7906 2
0 2 10326705.2376 2
0 4 40775341.6814 1
0 5 26342803.0964 2
0 7 11875753.3216 2
0.432253120382
1 6 1198411.02558 2
1 7 1545489.96614 2
1 10 27511427.9909 1
0.90930850584
2 7 750262.940888 2
2 8 12012343.5859 1
0.941213972294
3 6 23321277.5158 2
0.0
```

The created memory layer (green features) can be observed at the next image. It was as expected.

[image]

Comment: If I need to run the same in a single file, where my features are having >90% overlapping?

Comment: It is another question but you can use **combinations** method from **itertools** python module for same file (with only one features list).

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution that does not require python.

Add a new virtual layer with a query like :

```
WITH r AS (
SELECT 
    Basins800.rowid AS idGray, 
    area(Basins800.geometry) AS areaGray, 
    area(Intersection(Basins800.geometry, Severity.geometry)) AS aeraInter, 
    Basins800.geometry AS geomGray 
  FROM Basins800, Severity
)

SELECT *, areaInterSum/areaGray  AS overlap , geomGray 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
           idGray, 
           areaGray, 
           sum(areaInter) AS areaInterSum, 
           geomGray 
        FROM r 
        GROUP BY idGray) 
     WHERE areaInterSum/areaGray > 0.9
```

With :

- Basins800 as your layer you want filter with grey polygons
- Severity: your red layer overlapping.

The result will be a new layer with only all the grey plolygons >90% overlapped by red polygons, with a new field containing the overlap percent.

[image]

Hope this works.
I can add more details on the query if needed.

Note :
Your data contains very small polygons (coming from your raster processing and corresponding to a raster pixel (on the picture, we can see 4 polygons but there are 25 other small polygons). This make the query very slow to execute (Intersection function generates one feature for each couple of features from the two layers).

Comment: I'm getting an error when I run the query via the 'create a virtual layer' button. 

"Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS WITH r AS ("....rest of code here... followed by:  "1 - near "WITH": syntax error"

 I'm fairly new to QGIS. Can I create this virtual layer programatically? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's a link to download the shapefiles:
[link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4VMTQzC0SItYWw1Vk5jQndpWjQ&usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry, a bad copy between grey and gray (sorry for my aproximative english). I edited the query. It should works now. Why do you want to create the layer progamatically ? The advantages of virtual layer is that it is non-destructive, and if you edit your data (the gray or the red polygons), the virtual layer will autoatically update.

Comment: This is only one small piece of the process.  I have ~1000 of these maps to do, so automating the process will be extremely helpful.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error -->  "1 - near "WITH": syntax error".  

I plugged the local names for each layer in for the grayLayer and redLayer.  Is the local name what I should be using? ie: grey layer is labeled as "Basins_800", so I have code like "Basins_800.geometry"

Comment: As a quick answer you can save the virtual layer as Layer Definition File. Then you can load this file for each of your maps. Otherwise, it is possible to merge all your data before processing ?

Comment: Yes, the layer name is used. The query form of the virtual layer dialog has an autocompletion on layers names. I can't downlaod your file for testing with my connection (proxy error). I can try with an other connection in a couple of hours.

Comment: Not really possible to merge before processing.  These vectors are derived from a series of raster analyses.  Joining the rasters and performing the analysis on larger areas would be difficult and likely hang my cpu.  Thanks for looking into that error!

Comment: I tested your data. The problem was you don't have the id field for Basins800. So you can use "rowid". I editedmy answer with good parameters. A copy/paste of the query should works.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4VMTQzC0SItYWw1Vk5jQndpWjQ&usp=sharing) to **Severity** and **Basins800** shapefiles, I could understand the necessary geoprocess. I modified the code in:

[Programmatically finding polygons which are >90% overlapped by another vector polygon layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195373/programmatically-finding-polygons-which-are-90-overlapped-by-another-vector-po/195523#195523)

for getting this one:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

#for Severity
feats_lyr1 = [ feat for feat in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

#for Basins800
feats_lyr2 = [ feat for feat in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

selected_feats = []

print "processing..."

for i, feat1 in enumerate(feats_lyr1):
    for j, feat2 in enumerate(feats_lyr2):
        if feat1.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
            area1 = feat1.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry()).area()
            area2 = feat1.geometry().area()
            print i, j, area1, area2
    crit = area1/area2
    print crit
    if crit > 0.9:
        selected_feats.append(feat1)

epsg = layers[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           "mem_layer",
                           "memory")

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(selected_feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])

prov.addFeatures(selected_feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running the code, with these shapefiles at the Python Console of QGIS, in a few minutes I got a similar result as **Pierma**; where the memory layer had 31 features (different of 29 polygons got by him).

[image]

I am not going to debug the results because there are 1901*3528 = 6706728 interactions for features. However, the code looks promising.