# Calculating and using area of polygons in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, area

I am using the python code found in [Programmatically finding polygons which are >90% overlapped by another vector polygon layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195373/programmatically-finding-polygons-which-are-90-overlapped-by-another-vector-po/195376).

I get the following message

error: *NameError: name 'area1' is not defined*

Here is the concerned part of the code:

```
for i, feat1 in enumerate(feats_lyr1):
    for j, feat2 in enumerate(feats_lyr2):
        if feat1.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
            area1 = feat1.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry()).area()
            area2 = feat1.geometry().area()             
    crit =area1/area2
    if crit > 0.9:
        selected_feats.append(feat1)
```

After checking lots of things (geometry, CRS, ..), the only thing I see is that i have null area for couple of polygons.

- Is that possible that small areas, close to zero, are considered to be zero if considered as integer number?
- how to ensure the use of decimal number?

Comment: I think you should review your indentation because the last three lines of that code look like they should go in a level.

Comment: Put     `crit =area1/area2
    if crit > 0.9:
        selected_feats.append(feat1)` inside second `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an indentation problem:

```
for i, feat1 in enumerate(feats_lyr1):
    for j, feat2 in enumerate(feats_lyr2):
        if feat1.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
            area1 = feat1.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry()).area()
            area2 = feat2.geometry().area()
            crit =area1/area2
            if crit > 0.9:
                selected_feats.append(feat2)
```