# Using Sum in QGIS Attributes?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, summarizing

[image: QGIS attributes]

How to sum all 'Luas_sawah' attributes in accordance with the 'Kabupaten' attributes?

Comment: Like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/getting-tabular-statistics-from-table-using-qgis ?

Answer (score 2):

In the field calculator, try `sum()` function (it can be found under *Aggregates* group).

```
 sum( "Luas_sawah", group_by:= "Kabupaten")
```

It returns the sum of "Luas_sawah" field according to the "Kabupaten" group.

[image]