# Counting points in polygon to analyze data using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, count

I am using QGIS, and I have a shapefile that has 23 different land classifications. I have another file that lists coyote observations as points.  I would like to find out how many coyote observations are found within each of the 23 categories.

I can create a separate shapefile for each land type and then run "count points in polygon" for each one but does QGIS provide an alternative approach?

Comment: In ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap I would do Intersect followed by Summary Statistics (using land type to group by) so you could look for tools in QGIS with similar names.

Comment: This Group Stats plugin in this answer may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/43042/8104

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the algorithm ["Join attributes by location (Summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary).

For my example, I have two layers : **points** (your coyotes), **polygons** (your areas).

[image]

Run the algorithm `Join attributes by location (Summary)` with the following configuration :

[image]

As a result, you get a layer with **multiple statistics** (which you can filter when running the algorithm), the one you are interested in is **the count**.

[image]

Comment: The points are all within the same polygon (the metro area), so I was trying to do this without creating separate polygons for each land classification.

Comment: You don't have 23 features in your land layer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  There is one large polygon representing the metro area.  This polygon's attribute table has a column called "Land Use," in which there are 23 types of land use.  But there is only one polygon filled with points.  It looks like your solution would work if I had separate polygons representing each land use type.

Comment: Before using my algorithm, try using `multipart to singlepart` algorithm and dissolve them thanks to your classification field. Once you have 23 polygons you will be able to use my algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there are two layers, a point layer called *'points'* and a polygon layer called *'polygons'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to find out how many coyote observations are found within each of the categories*.

```sql
SELECT
    poly.*,
    COUNT(*) AS "numpois"
FROM
    "polygons" AS poly
JOIN
    "points" AS poi
    ON st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
GROUP BY
    poly."id"
```

The output point layer with its attribute table will look like

[image: output1]

Mind, that if some fields have to be concatenated then apply the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/) function. So, the new query will look like

```sql
SELECT
    poly.*,
    COUNT(*) AS "numpois",
    GROUP_CONCAT(poi."Coyote") AS Coyotes
FROM
    "polygons" AS poly
JOIN
    "points" AS poi
    ON st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
GROUP BY
    poly."id"
```

And the output

[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question was answered but just thought I would provide an alternative - the ["Point Sampling Tool"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) plugin in QGIS is helpful in doing exactly what you describe.

Recommend checking it out and then importing the file to R or Excel for further analysis.